# How can i convert the string value to date time value and assign it to DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker, datetime-parsing

I stored a date value and retrieve it and the format of the date in the string is `yyMMdd`.
Now when the user loads that from the string i would like to select the DateTimePicker as the user loaded date.

Sample code:

```
string strDate = strRead.Substring(23, 6);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
```

Can any one give me an idea for the next?

Comment: How are you storing the date? Perhaps you do not need to return it as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way, I guess:

```
DateTimePicker p = new DateTimePicker();
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("101025", "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    p.Value = result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
string strDate = strRead.Substring(23, 6);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
dateTimePicker.Value = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dateTimePicker.Value = dt;
dateTimePicker.Focus(); //if by Select to meant to give it the focus
```